# How can I save my table from truncate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, truncate

I need to restrict my table from `update` and `delete`.

For `Update` and `Delete` I'm Using an `Instead of` trigger, and its working fine.

But if I use the **`TRUNCATE`** Command, it erases my data.

I need to restrict `truncate` or any other table modification process.

Can anyone give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want others to be able to run `TRUNCATE` against the table?

Comment: one word: permissions.

Comment: Yes Mr.Larnu. No one can able to perform TRUNCATE against the table

Comment: Either permissions or restrictions can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Truncate is a DDL command, and delete DML. Permissions is what you need to look into, you can explicitly deny access to just TRUNCATE if necessary, deny will always override any allow permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a `TRUNCATE` statement you need to have the `ALTER` permissions on the object; as per the documentation: [TRUNCATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) - Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions).

If you want to stop a user/role from using the `TRUNCATE` statement on a table, you will need to use the following (Replacing the text in braces (`{}`)):

```
USE {YourDatabase}
DENY ALTER ON {YourTable} TO {User/Role};
```

You can easily test if this works with a quick test script:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (Id int IDENTITY(1,1), String varchar(10));

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (String)
VALUES ('asdfhj'),('asdjkas'),('asdjkhsad');
GO

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;

ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER TestUser;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER TestUser;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TestTable; --This works
GO
REVERT;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable;

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (String)
VALUES ('asdfhj'),('asdjkas'),('asdjkhsad');

DENY ALTER ON dbo.TestTable TO TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TestTable; --This fails
GO
REVERT;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
DROP USER TestUser;
```