# How to prevent truncate data on the tables which have been enabled change tracking?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

We have enabeld change tracking on some tables. Recently, we found that someone truncating the data on one table. Is it possible to prevent user truncating data on the tables which have been enabled change tracking?

The version of SQL Server is SQL Server 2008 R2 and above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save my table from truncate in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445430/how-can-i-save-my-table-from-truncate-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

TRUNCATE TABLE requires ALTER TABLE permission at a minimum. To find out which tables have change tracking enabled, run:

```
`USE <database name>
GO
SELECT s.name AS Schema_Name 
       ,tb.name AS Table_Name
       ,tb.object_id, tb.type
       ,tb.type_desc 
       ,tb.is_tracked_by_cdc
FROM sys.tables tb
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = tb.schema_id
`WHERE tb.is_tracked_by_cdc = 1`
```

For each table, revoke ALTER TABLE permissions from database level principals (database users, roles or application roles) who shouldn't have them:

`REVOKE ALTER TABLE ON <table name> FROM <principal name>`